# How to get a 3D point on a plane (which is represented as normal and offset from origin)?

Tags: game-engine, computational-geometry, game-physics, raytracing

I know how to get the intersection point between a ray and a plane, if I know the ray and
a point on the plane, and the plane normal.

In the code I use the plane is represented as signed offset from origin, and normal, and I 
need to get some, any point on the plane. How to do this?

So, the plane equation: Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, and I know A,B and C, that is basically
the normal of the plane and I know D, which is the signed distance from the origin. And
my question is, given that how do I get some 3D point on the plane?

Thanks

Comment: isn't any point satisfying the equation o point on the plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get one plane point by intersecting plane with a ray (line) :-)

Choose some point `P=(x,y,z)`, calculate `w=Ax+By+Cz`.

If `w=-D` than `P` is on the plane.

For `w!=-D`, choose some direction `Q=(dx,dy,dz)` for which `l=Adx+Bdy+Cdz!=0`, e.g. `q=(A,0,0)`, if `B!=0` or `C!=0`. Than point `P+l*Q/w` is on the plane.

Answer (score 4):

If (A, B, C) are normalized vector, the point on the plane closest to original is simply:

(-AD, -BD, -CD)

This can be easily known from your description that (A, B, C) is the plane normal, and D is the distance between the plane and origin.

This method is simple and do not need any branching.

[Point on plane closest to origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_on_plane_closest_to_origin)